# Is it possible to request a token on behalf of a user from Web API in Node.js using adal-node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, access-token, adal

In a C# API it is possible to request a token on behalf of another client by providing a 'UserAssertion' token provider. How can this be achieved in a Nodejs application using adal-node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADAL Node does not support the on-behalf-of flow.  [There's an active request](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs/pull/159) to support this in ADAL Node, I'd recommend adding more information about the scenario you're trying to implement to that request.

There's nothing preventing it from being technically possible, and the token service endpoints are well-documented.  You'll need to take the incoming access token, and post it to the service, here's an example.

```
>  POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1 Host: login.microsoftonline.com
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
> grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer
> &client_id=625391af-c675-43e5-8e44-edd3e30ceb15
> &client_secret=0Y1W%2BY3yYb3d9N8vSjvm8WrGzVZaAaHbHHcGbcgG%2BoI%3D
> &resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.windows.net
> &assertion=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6InowMzl6ZHNGdWl6cEJmQlZLMVRuMjVRSFlPMCIsImtpZCI6InowMzl6ZHNGdWl6cEJmQlZLMVRuMjVRSFlPMCJ9.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.R-Ke-XO7lK0r5uLwxB8g5CrcPAwRln5SccJCfEjU6IUqpqcjWcDzeDdNOySiVPDU_ZU5knJmzRCF8fcjFtPsaA4R7vdIEbDuOur15FXSvE8FvVSjP_49OH6hBYqoSUAslN3FMfbO6Z8YfCIY4tSOB2I6ahQ_x4ZWFWglC3w5mK-_4iX81bqi95eV4RUKefUuHhQDXtWhrSgIEC0YiluMvA4TnaJdLq_tWXIc4_Tq_KfpkvI004ONKgU7EAMEr1wZ4aDcJV2yf22gQ1sCSig6EGSTmmzDuEPsYiyd4NhidRZJP4HiiQh-hePBQsgcSgYGvz9wC6n57ufYKh2wm_Ti3Q
> &requested_token_use=on_behalf_of &scope=openid
```

The app will then (on success) receive the following info back.

```
{
    "token_type":"Bearer",
    "scope":"User.Read",
    "expires_in":"43482",
    "ext_expires_in":"302683",
    "expires_on":"1493466951",
    "not_before":"1493423168",
    "resource":"https://graph.windows.net",
    "access_token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6InowMzl6ZHNGdWl6cEJmQlZLMVRuMjVRSFlPMCIsImtpZCI6InowMzl6ZHNGdWl6cEJmQlZLMVRuMjVRSFlPMCJ9.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.cqmUVjfVbqWsxJLUI1Z4FRx1mNQAHP-L0F4EMN09r8FY9bIKeO-0q1eTdP11Nkj_k4BmtaZsTcK_mUygdMqEp9AfyVyA1HYvokcgGCW_Z6DMlVGqlIU4ssEkL9abgl1REHElPhpwBFFBBenOk9iHddD1GddTn6vJbKC3qAaNM5VarjSPu50bVvCrqKNvFixTb5bbdnSz-Qr6n6ACiEimiI1aNOPR2DeKUyWBPaQcU5EAK0ef5IsVJC1yaYDlAcUYIILMDLCD9ebjsy0t9pj_7lvjzUSrbMdSCCdzCqez_MSNxrk1Nu9AecugkBYp3UVUZOIyythVrj6-sVvLZKUutQ",
    "refresh_token":"AQABAAAAAABnfiG-mA6NTae7CdWW7QfdjKGu9-t1scy_TDEmLi4eLQMjJGt_nAoVu6A4oSu1KsRiz8XyQIPKQxSGfbf2FoSK-hm2K8TYzbJuswYusQpJaHUQnSqEvdaCeFuqXHBv84wjFhuanzF9dQZB_Ng5za9xKlUENrNtlq9XuLNVKzxEyeUM7JyxzdY7JiEphWImwgOYf6II316d0Z6-H3oYsFezf4Xsjz-MOBYEov0P64UaB5nJMvDyApV-NWpgklLASfNoSPGb67Bc02aFRZrm4kLk-xTl6eKE6hSo0XU2z2t70stFJDxvNQobnvNHrAmBaHWPAcC3FGwFnBOojpZB2tzG1gLEbmdROVDp8kHEYAwnRK947Py12fJNKExUdN0njmXrKxNZ_fEM33LHW1Tf4kMX_GvNmbWHtBnIyG0w5emb-b54ef5AwV5_tGUeivTCCysgucEc-S7G8Cz0xNJ_BOiM_4bAv9iFmrm9STkltpz0-Tftg8WKmaJiC0xXj6uTf4ZkX79mJJIuuM7XP4ARIcLpkktyg2Iym9jcZqymRkGH2Rm9sxBwC4eeZXM7M5a7TJ-5CqOdfuE3sBPq40RdEWMFLcrAzFvP0VDR8NKHIrPR1AcUruat9DETmTNJukdlJN3O41nWdZOVoJM-uKN3uz2wQ2Ld1z0Mb9_6YfMox9KTJNzRzcL52r4V_y3kB6ekaOZ9wQ3HxGBQ4zFt-2U0mSszIAA",
    "id_token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJub25lIn0.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."
}
```

You can then extract the `access_token` and use it against resource in a `bearer` request.  You'll also want to track the `access_token` expiration so you can use the `refresh_token` for renewal.

If you do want to implement in manually, here's the [on-behalf-of reference documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-on-behalf-of). I recommend checking out the possible errors as well so the app can handle multi-factor auth and conditional access challenges.